# easy_install/curl fails because of "SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

Tags: python, ssl, curl, easy-install

I recently installed a new wildcard SHA256 certificate from Comodo. It's a "Premium SSL" cert.

I am now unable to curl/wget, or anything that uses those common SSL libraries, files from the server. I usually get the following message back:

```
SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

This is particularly an issue when I run easy_install and use our custom cheeseshop as the index, which is using the new cert.

I've tried running `sudo update-ca-certificates` but that didn't resolve the issue.

My Apache config has the following:

```
SSLEngine                    on
SSLCertificateFile           /etc/ssl/localcerts/domain.net.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile        /etc/ssl/localcerts/domain.net.key
SSLCertificateChainFile      /etc/ssl/localcerts/domain.net.ca-bundle
```

When I view the site in Chrome or Firefox, I get no errors. I've used online SSL Analysers as well which seem to pass fine.

If I pass the ca-bundle file given to me by Comodo direcly into curl, it works, but otherwise it doesn't.

My understanding is that this is because it's not in /etc/ssl/certs/cacerts.pem. I tried adding the bundled certs in as well, but it didn't work.

What's the best way to resolve this? We're using easy_install with Chef when deploying, so I'd like to avoid having to point to the ca bundle if at all possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look in the results from the online analyzers for chain issues? Did you try [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Hi - yes, and it says it passes. Chain issues returns the following:

Certificates provided 3 (4441 bytes)
Chain issues None

Comment: Could you maybe publish the URL you used with curl so that one can look for problems? Also version of curl including compile time options (which SSL stack was used?) and platform could be significant information.